# Browser Maximum HTTP Request (Host vs IP Address)

Tags: http

We are looking to host images on separate sub-domain. We just want to map subdomain on same IP Address.

i.e images for testserver.com are hosted on img.testserver.com and both testserver.com & img.testserver.com mapped to same IP Address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

I believe IE7 permits max 2 concurrent connection per host.

Will IE7 allow 4 concurrent request (2 for testserver.com & img.testserver.com each)?

Comment: This won't help performance because HTTP 1.1 already supports persistent connections. See [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) section 8.1.1, particularly this part: "HTTP requests and responses can be pipelined on a connection. Pipelining allows a client to make multiple requests without waiting for each response, allowing a single TCP connection to be used much more efficiently, with much lower elapsed time."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will IE7 allow 4 concurrent request (2 for testserver.com & img.testserver.com each)?

That's correct.

Check this page for how many connections that can be made per host and overall: http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network